# How is it not a StackOverflowException when a class has a field of the same class?

Tags: class, language-agnostic, stack-overflow

If a class T has a field of type T, how is there not a StackOverflow exception? Because if you create an object of T, there will be another T object inside of it, and that T object will in turn have its own T object, and on and on and on.

Okay I know this question is very confusing, and this is probably not the website to answer these types questions, but I'm just curious.

**Edit:**

Okay so here is an example to make myself more clear on what I mean:

```
class T {
    T t = new T();
}
```

So if you create an object of T, you will be also creating another object of T, which in turn will have its own object of T, and so on and so forth. What I am asking is why is that not a StackOverflow, since an infinite chain of T's will be created?

I don't know if that helped.

Comment: What language ?

Comment: I believe he (or she) is asking a general, conceptual question. I think it's valid so I +1-ed it.

Comment: @Ed. Nevertheless there is no 'general, conceptual' answer. The answer varies by language. In C++ for example it *is* either a stack overflow, or maybe a compilation error, as the object size is infinite. The term `StackOverflowException` strongly suggests Java.

Comment: Sounds like my answer could do with an edit, then?

Comment: @Ed. I have no idea. It's up to the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, in most (all?) programming languages, objects with properties that are complex data items do not store those full data items within their allocated space, rather they allocate enough space for a pointer or reference to that object. To use Perl terms:

```
package T;
use Moo;
use Types::Standard -all;
has ref_to_t => (is => 'ro', isa => InstanceOf['T']); # notice not "required"
1;
```

Then with:

```
my $obj1 = T->new;
my $obj2 = T->new(ref_to_t => undef);
my $obj3 = T->new(ref_to_t => $obj2);
```

This demonstrates three ways the situation does not lead to Armageddon:

- `$obj1` has (because this is how Perl's `Moo` works) no space allocated at all for the `ref_to_t`.
- `$obj2` has space allocated, but only enough for a reference to another object, that is null or undefined.
- `$obj3` has also space allocated, also only for a reference.

Comment: "(all?)" - I'm not sure about others, but C++ doesn't all you to have a property the same type as the class/struct, since C++ automatically constructs an object with the default constructor when it isn't explicitly constructed. To get around this, you have to use a pointer of some kind since `nullptr` is a thing.